# How to align the plot legends in the following way?

Tags: plotting, syntax, legending, labeling

Consider example

```
   ContourPlot[{(x - 2)^2 + (y - 2)^2 == 
       12, (x + 2)^3 + (y + 2)^3 ==8}, {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}, 
     PlotLegends -> 
      Placed[{Style["Region 1", 20], Style["Region 2", 20]}, {0.7, 0.82}]]
```

The result is the picture on the left. Could you please tell me to change the colour of the legend text and set for each plot legend set its own coordinate, see the picture on the right?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
Show[{
  ContourPlot[{(x - 2)^2 + (y - 2)^2 == 12, (x + 2)^3 + (y + 2)^3 == 
     8}, {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}, ContourStyle -> {Blue, Orange}],
  Graphics[{Text[Style["Region 1", 20, Blue], Scaled[{0.8, 0.8}]],

    Text[Style["Region 2", 20, Orange], Scaled[{0.2, 0.2}]]
    }]
  }]
```

[image]

Done. Have fun!

Comment: Maybe a bit more "authomatic": `Show[ContourPlot[(x - 2)^2 + (y - 2)^2 == 12, {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}, 
  ContourStyle -> Blue, 
  PlotLegends -> Placed[{"Region 1"}, {Right, Top}]], 
 ContourPlot[(x + 2)^3 + (y + 2)^3 == 8, {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}, 
  ContourStyle -> Orange, 
  PlotLegends -> Placed[{"Region 2"}, {Left, Bottom}]]]`

Answer (score 5):

```
labels = Style[#, 20] & /@ {"Region 1", "Region 2"};
colors = ColorData[97] /@ {1, 2};
positions = {{7, 7} / 10, {1, 1} / 4};

ContourPlot[{(x - 2)^2 + (y - 2)^2 == 12, (x + 2)^3 + (y + 2)^3 ==  8}, 
 {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}, 
 PlotLegends -> ( Placed[Style@##2, #] & @@@ Transpose[{positions, labels, colors}])]
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can replace `PlotLegends -> ...` with

```
Epilog -> (Text[Style[##2], Scaled@#] & @@@ Transpose[{positions, labels, colors}])
```

to get the same picture.

**Update:** You can also get `positions` using `ImplicitRegion` and `RegionCentroid` :

```
contours = {(x - 2)^2 + (y - 2)^2 == 12, (x + 2)^3 + (y + 2)^3 == 8} ; 
positions = Quiet @ N @ RegionCentroid[ImplicitRegion[# /. 
   Equal -> LessEqual, {{x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4} }] ] & /@ contours
```

> {{1.46315, 1.46315}, {-2.03791, -2.03791}}

Notes: (1)  Despite the warning message (suppressed above with `Quiet`) `RegionCentroid` gives the correct coordinates. (2) If you use this with `Epilog` you should remove `Scaled`.

Comment: Nice answer, first time I've ever seen `##n` used.